# php code which i am trying to change in CF

Tags: php, coldfusion, lucee

I am working on something which unfortunately does not have anything in CF, so there are few things which i am trying to do to convert but some functions which i am not sure what is the equivalent of those in Coldfusion, any guidance will be helpful

```
$nonce = explode(' ', microtime());
$request['nonce'] = $nonce[1] . str_pad(substr($nonce[0], 2, 6), 6, '0');
```

for the above, to me it seems just a timestamp in ACF , if i am doing wrong please guide, because i am not sure what explode and str_pad is doing here

so my CF equivalent is:

```
<cfset nonce = createobject("java","java.lang.System").currentTimeMillis() & "000">
```

what is `base64_decode` and `base64_encode` of PHP in ACF

i think `binaryencode` and `binmarydecode` but i am not sure

and i tried finding a lot what is `http_build_query` in PHP as to Coldfusion, but i think its `cfhttp` but i have no clue

Comment: My recommended method for rewriting something in another programming language is to first write it out in whatever language you speak, English, French, whatever.  Then use that document as a specification.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you bookmark the main Adobe ColdFusion documentation, as well as the community docs:

- https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/user-guide.html
- https://cfdocs.org/

If you just Google "base64 encode with ColdFusion", you'll find the related functions.

https://cfdocs.org/tobase64

```
toBase64(string_or_object [, encoding]) → returns string
```

https://cfdocs.org/tobinary

```
toBinary(base64_or_object) → returns binary
```

You won't find a lot of resources about directly converting from CF to PHP or vice-versa. But if you look up what the actual PHP function *DOES*, then you're more likely to find the related CF function.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

```
http_build_query ( mixed $query_data , string $numeric_prefix = ? , string $arg_separator = ? , int $enc_type = PHP_QUERY_RFC1738 ) : string
```

> Generates a URL-encoded query string from the associative (or indexed) array provided.

This takes the result of a query in PHP and converts it to the query string for a URL.

```
column1=A&column2=B
```

I don't think there's a CF function that does exactly that, but you can loop over the columns in the result of a `cfquery` and create the same output string using the CF function `encodeForURL()` on the query string parameter values.

Comment: Thanks, i know there are some hicups while finding the equivalents in ACF, Another catch is i think my nounce is correct because it seems you did not mentioned it, because i had no clue what the str_pad be in Coldfusion, as per PHP, it seems it is adding padding to the string on the one of the side, left or right

Answer (score 0):

There's a third-party function to do that:

```
/**
 * Converts a structure to a URL query string.
 * 
 * @param struct      Structure of key/value pairs you want converted to URL parameters 
 * @param keyValueDelim      Delimiter for the keys/values.  Default is the equal sign (=). 
 * @param queryStrDelim      Delimiter separating url parameters.  Default is the ampersand (&). 
 * @return Returns a string. 
 * @author Erki Esken (erki@dreamdrummer.com) 
 * @version 1, December 17, 2001 
 */
function StructToQueryString(struct) {
  var qstr = "";
  var delim1 = "=";
  var delim2 = "&";

  switch (ArrayLen(Arguments)) {
    case "3":
      delim2 = Arguments[3];
    case "2":
      delim1 = Arguments[2];
  }
    
  for (key in struct) {
    qstr = ListAppend(qstr, URLEncodedFormat(LCase(key)) & delim1 & URLEncodedFormat(struct[key]), delim2);
  }
  return qstr;
}
```

Source: https://cflib.org/udf/StructToQueryString

Comment: A little warning, this function lower-cases each query parameter name. You can disable that by removing "LCase()".